# Progressbar inside NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, macos, progress-bar, nstableview

I've a list of items shown in NSTableView.I need to show a progress bar corresponding to each item inside the table view.How can i do that?

Thanks,

LS Developer

Comment: Lion has new view-based tables which are a joy to work with for this very reason. For non-Lion support, however, Ernie's answer is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create a custom `NSCell` and draw a `NSProgressIndicator` inside.
In Interface Builder you can change the default tableview cell class name to your custom class name in order to use it.

Checkout the examples by CocoaDev:
[CocoaDev - NSViewInNSTableView](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSViewInNSTableView)